# Salvar os bytes de um arquivo

Tags: c#

Estou fazendo um aplicativo que necessita da leitura dos bytes de um arquivo fixo, estou conseguindo fazer a leitura claramente, porém, me incomoda o fato do arquivo precisar acompanhar o meu aplicativo toda vez que ele for iniciado. Por acaso tem como eu 'salvar' esses bytes dentro do meu aplicativo ou algo do tipo?

Comment: Bem vindo ao SP. Poste o código que vc já fez e mostra onde que está ocorrendo o problema/dificuldade.

Comment: Obrigado pelas boas vindas :D, o código que eu fiz é apenas passar o arquivo para um array de bytes e vice versa (array de bytes -> *.exe), mas como eu expliquei, eu quero quebrar a dependência do arquivo original, eu quero ter ele "hardcoded" no meu código pra eu construir ele do zero quando achar conveniente, só não consigo pensar em como posso salvar esse array de bytes para utilizar em novas instâncias da aplicação, você sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: Quem negativou, por gentileza, que se pronuncie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pense bem, não existe milagre. Vc quer tirar dados de um arquivo e colocar seu conteúdo dentro do seu código. No final esses dados continuam salvos em algum lugar - no seus fontes ou binários. Então, pq se importar?

Adicionar esse arquivo ao projeto, marque para sempre copiar o arquivo nos builds e toca pra frente a solução. Agora, se realmente quiser fazer isso:

Leia os dados do arquivo, crie um buffer e depois crie esse buffer como código C#.

```
var buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(caminhoDoArquivoBinario);
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); // breakpoint após a leitura do buffer
```

Vá então na `Imediate Window` e faça:

```
buffer <ENTER>
```

Copie o que foi gerado e cole em algum arquivo `.cs`.